# WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable with hadoop-2.6.0

Tags: hadoop

I have started working in hadoop, i am a beginner. I have succuefully install the hadoop-2.6.0 in ubuntu 15.04 64 bit.
The commond like start-all.sh, start-dfs.sh etc are working nicely.

I am facing the problem when i am trying to move the local file system to HDFS.

Like in copyFromLocal command:
hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal ~/Hadoop/test/text2.txt ~/Hadoop/test_hds/input.txt
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

15/06/04 23:18:29 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
copyFromLocal: Call From royaljay-Inspiron-N4010/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Same problem in mkdir command:

hadoop dfs -put ~/test/test/test1.txt hd.txt
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

15/06/03 20:49:18 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

put: Cannot create file/user/hduser/hd.txt.*COPYING*. Name node is in safe mode.

I have found many solutions, but no one is working out.

If anyone have idea about this please tell me.

Comment: hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal ~/Hadoop/test/text2.txt ~/Hadoop/test_hds/input.txt
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

15/06/04 23:29:55 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
copyFromLocal: `/home/hduser/Hadoop/test_hds/input.txt': No such file or directory

Comment: Do you have the hadoop client jars downloaded and setup to work correctly? That seems like it could be the issue  - I've run into that in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
>   Instead use the hdfs command for it.

You should not use `hadoop dfs`, instead use the following command:

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal ...
```

Do not use `~`, instead mention full path like `/home/hadoop/Hadoop/test/text2.txt`

> Call From royaljay-Inspiron-N4010/**127.0.1.1** to localhost:9000 failed
>   on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused; For more details see:
>   http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

`127.0.1.1` will cause loopback problems. Remove the line with `127.0.1.1` from `/etc/hosts`.

> **NOTE:** For copying files from local filesystem to HDFS, try using **-put** command instead of **-copyFromLocal**.

Comment: WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable for hadoop fs -ls command